# RC circuit: is order of resistance and capacitor important?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

in a RC circuit is order of resistance and capacitor important?

Typically there is the battery then the capacitor then the resistance, but is it ok if I draw with the battery then the resistance and then the capacitor?

Answer (score 1):

The two circuits you describe:

[image: Circuits]

are basically the same. For example the change of the current with time when we first connect the battery will be the same. There are some obvious but minor differences, for example in the left circuit when we first connect the battery $V_a$ starts at zero and rises to $V$, while in the right circuit $V_a$ starts at $V$ and falls to zero. Aside from this, when you connect a capacitor and resistor in series it doesn't matter which way round you connect them.

Comment: Easier to turn the cell around?

Comment: @Farcher - not if the cap is electrolytic

Comment: It becomes a more interesting problem if you consider actual nonlinearities in the ideal linear components. In this case, depending on the type of nonlinearity, superposition may not hold and order may matter. What's one example of nonlinearity that would matter? If the source were a high frequency RF source layout, order indeed matters.